# Ignore entities persistence from a dependency

Tags: java, maven, wildfly-8

I'm working on a web application that needs some dependencies, one of those being

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>be.cocof.ddp</groupId>
        <artifactId>ddp-model</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>          
    </dependency>
```

(this dependency is developed by a 3rd-party which I can have contact with)

In this particular dependency, there are entities. In the pom.xml file, if I add the dependency like I typed above, I have an error in the deployment in wildfly : basically I use those entities but I don't have the mapped tables in my local database. Except that I only use those entities because I need them to build a request to send through a REST service developed by the same developer of the dependency. I don't need to persist all the entities information in my database.

So, how I can use this dependency without having to create tables in my database ?

Comment: Does the model artifact contain both the DTOs and entities or are they using "raw" entries in their REST  implementation?

Comment: @WillT They put the DTO in one .jar and the entities in another

Comment: If they are in separate jars, why can't you just include only the dto jar in your project?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you cannot deploy your application without creation of the tables related to the entities. If using hibernate, you can set the property "hbm.ddl.auto-create" to "true" . This will automatically create the tables related to the entities while starting the server.